# Convert string to uri in its simple form .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert for example:

***Aión*** to URI string, so using `System.Uri.EscapeDataString` this translates as *Ai%C3%B3n* but I expect *Ai%F3n*

How can I translate characters, the way I want?

**I'm using a regular winform application not a ASP page**

Comment: Can you not reference System.Web.dll and use HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: I already checked that and produces same output as you say below (and is HttpUtility not HtmlUtility

Comment: This almost sounds like a character set issue.

Comment: This post is on the lines of what might be needed, I'll have another look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072409/url-encode-all-non-alpha-numeric-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul McCowat and the last asnwer on that link I came up with a function that does what I want:

```
public static string ConvertToUri(string uri_string)
        {
            StringBuilder Encoded = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char Ch in uri_string)
            {
                if (Uri.EscapeUriString(Ch.ToString()) != Ch.ToString())
                {
                    Encoded.Append("%");
                    Encoded.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Ch.ToString())[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Encoded.Append(Ch);
                }
            }
            return Encoded.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: This code does not produce correct results for characters with code above 256 range. Make sure you are happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

[Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This would give you

> ```
> "Ai&#243;n"
> ```

Comment: If it outputs that, this is not what i need... i exactly need Ai%F3n and... in a non-server application i just can't find the function